# Installation error: legacy-install-failure pyoptimus

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pyoptimus in a conda virtual environment, but I'm getting this error every time.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> llvmlite
```

As per the official documentation, I've tried creating different environments with different versions of python, but it doesn't seem to work!

Please let me know if anyone knows a way around the problem. Thanks!